# Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component issue on my project

Tags: reactjs

I am using fetching google geometry data by using redux actions. I have an issue about this. When redirect to a new page, I have a warning message : **Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.**

Actually, I am pretty new about React. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

The followings are codes I have built as of now.

```
class BranchList extends Component {
  startInterval;

  state = {
     city: "",
     _isMounted: false
  };

  setTodayWeatherInfo = city => {

     // invoke actions with parameter, city
     // once I remove this one, no warning message generated
     this.props.setLocation(city); 

     this.props.additionalTodayWeatherInfo(city);
     if (this.startInterval) clearInterval(this.startInterval);
     this.startInterval = setInterval(() => {
     this.props.additionalTodayWeatherInfo(city);
    }, 300000);

  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const city = sessionStorage.branch_city || options[0].value;

    this.setState({
           city,
          _isMounted: true
    });

    this.setTodayWeatherInfo(city);
 }

 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.city !== nextState.city ? true : false;
 }

 componentWillUnmount() {
   this.setState({ _isMounted: false });
   clearInterval(this.startInterval);
   this.startInterval = false;
}

render() {
   if (!this.state.city) return <div />;
   //this.props.location(this.state.city);
     return (
       <div>
         <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-warning">
         <div className="text-center w-100">
          <h4>Welcome to Korean Restaurant in {`${this.state.city}`}</h4>
       </div>
       <div className="mx-auto text-center w-50">
        <SelectCity
          setCity={city => {
            this.setState({ city });
            this.setTodayWeatherInfo(city);
          }}
          refreshStatus={this.props.refreshStatus}
        />
        </div>
       </nav>
      </div>
     );
   }
 }

 export default connect(
   null,
  { additionalTodayWeatherInfo, setLocation }
 )(BranchList);
```

Then, this.props.setLocation(city) call actions as followed. Once I get rid of this.props.setLocation(city), it does not generate the warning message. I need to give up some functions associated with this, though.

```
 export function setLocation(branch_city) {
    const url = `${GoogleURL}=${branch_city}&key=${
     process.env.REACT_APP_GMAP_API_KEY
 }`;

    const request = axios.get(url);

    return {
    type: FETCH_LOCATION,
    payload: request
};
```

}
Is there any way to prevent the warning message?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly this.props.setLocation(city) does, but I believe it is definitely affecting the DOM, the issue here is, even after you get out of this BranchList component, you are still trying to change the component which is not present in the DOM anymore, just as the way you cleared the setInterval in componentWillUnmount method, try to stop calling setLocation method

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know how to stop it?

Comment: I tried to do if(_isMounted) {

      this.props.setLocation(city);
    }                                                            ===> it does not work.

Comment: I hope you wrote the code with the right syntax, if(this.state._isMounted){ }

Comment: even if that doesn't work then what I would do is I would give an id to the div element <div id="city"> .... </div> that you are rendering and in shouldComponentUpdate method I would write a if condition statement like this if(document.getElementById("city")){ }, this check will update the state only when the div element with id="city" is mounted